# z-index on firefox - internet explorer is not working. Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I have a bootstrap modal with jquery datepicker.

The datepicker has this style:

```
.datepicker{ z-index:1000;}
```

Works fine on google chrome, and it looks like this:

[image]

In internet explorer 10 / firefox  looks like this

[image]

This is the modal html:

```
<div name="fechaAprobacionModal<?php echo $i; ?>" id="fechaAprobacionModal<?php echo $i; ?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
    <h4 id="myModalLabel">Indicar Aprobaci&oacute;n de Facturas de Programas Especiales </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

            <p> <div class="texto_importante" style="margin-top:4px;"> Fecha Aprobaci&oacute;n: </div>  

                <div class="input-prepend">
                  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>

                   <input type="text" id="fechaid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>"/>
                </div>

            </p>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-small" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-info" id="guardar<?php echo $i; ?>">Guardar</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Any hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you overwritten any of the bootstrap CSS classes? This is the likely culprit if it works properly on the bootstrap demo site. Also can you create a fiddle with a demo.

Comment: I have not overwritten any of the bootstrap CSS clases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following:

```
<div class="input-prepend" style="z-index:4000;">

    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    <input style="z-index:2000;"  type="text" name="fecha_culminacion" id="fechaid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>"/>

</div>
```

I gave the parent element a higher z-index.

And I found the solution here: [internet explorer z-index bug](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)

Answer (score 0):

For a z-index to work properly in all browsers, it requires it's position to be set to fixed, absolute or relative.

```
.datepicker{ z-index:1000; position: relative; }
```

Reference: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: I tried but it didn't solve the problem. I found another solution.

Comment: I couldn't have seen that was the problem without seeing the entire css. But I'm glad you've got it solved.